# asp:ImageButton getting broken when loading debugging ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton, broken-image

Hi I have a imageButton and when I load IE 7, it shows a broken image for the picture, although when I go into Design in VS2010 it shows the picture.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="calendarImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="d:\mydocuments\ALM\ALM\ALM\imgs\calendar_button.jpg" Height="21px" Width="24px" />
```

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: could you change your ImageUrl to a location that is relative to the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to set `ImageUrl="d:\mydocuments\ALM\ALM\ALM\imgs\calendar_button.jpg"` in this way ?

You should put these images in your Website folder, then set the path like...

```
ImageUrl="~/imgs/calendar_button.jpg"
```

If you really want to set ImageURL the way you are proposing, I would not recommend it, but you can do it like...

```
ImageUrl="d:\\mydocuments\\ALM\\ALM\\ALM\imgs\\calendar_button.jpg"
```

You need to use `double slash` instead `single slash`  in path